PyCharm configura automáticamente Python 3.10 en lugar de Python 3.12 al crear un nuevo entorno virtual
Hola comunidad de Stack Overflow,
Estoy enfrentando un problema con PyCharm donde, al intentar configurar un nuevo entorno virtual con Python 3.12 como base, el IDE automáticamente lo configura con Python 3.10. A pesar de seleccionar explícitamente el ejecutable de Python 3.12 durante la configuración del nuevo entorno virtual, el entorno creado muestra Python 3.10.
Detalles:

Sistema Operativo: e.g., Windows 10, macOS Big Sur
Versión de PyCharm:versión de PyCharm,  2022.3.3]
Pasos seguidos:

Voy a Preferences > Python Interpreter en PyCharm.
Hago clic en Add Interpreter.
Elijo Virtualenv Environment > New environment.
En Base Interpreter, selecciono la ruta de Python 3.12 (/usr/local/bin/python3.12).
Especifico una ubicación completamente nueva y vacía para el entorno.
Creo el entorno, pero se muestra como Python 3.10 en PyCharm.



Intentos de solución:

He intentado limpiar la caché de PyCharm con Invalidate Caches / Restart.
He verificado que la ruta del ejecutable de Python 3.12 es correcta mediante el comando python3.12 --version en la terminal.
He reiniciado PyCharm y mi computadora.

Pregunta:
¿Por qué PyCharm está configurando incorrectamente el entorno virtual con Python 3.10 en lugar de Python 3.12, y cómo puedo resolver este problema?
Agradecería cualquier ayuda o sugerencia que pudieran proporcionarme.

La verdad es que no sé que podría ocasionar este problema. En mi caso, prefiero crear los entornos virtuales fuera de el IDE usando directamente python desde el terminal, y luego configurar el IDE. También, como pruebo diferentes librerías y versiones, utilizo conda para manejar los entornos virtuales. Prueba cualquiera de estas dos opciones

Muchas gracias por tu respuesta! Ok, crearé el entorno virtual directo en la terminal por fuera del IDE pero a que te refieres con la parte de luego configurar el IDE? Que hago luego en el IDE? Gracias

De vuelta en el VS Code, presiona Ctrl+shift+P para abrir la paleta de comandos y escribir "Python Seleccionar intérprete" y debería aparecer el entorno virtual creado

Muchas gracias, hice lo de Conda pero el error sigue siendo el mismo, es algo relacionado a Certifi y tampoco logra instalarlo desde Conda, el error es el mismo aunque ponga pip install... No sé que hacer..

Si editas tu post y añades el mesaje de error, sería mucho mejor para poder ayudarte

Muchas gracias por la buena onda y la ayuda. Ahí edité el post, y puse también el erroe que siempre me salta aunque intente descargar certifi con pip. Está bastante difìcil, también te puse lo que me ponen Gemini y ChatGpt al respecto. Muchas gracias.

https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/619556/357614
Ahí está mi pregunta!! En vez de editarse creo que la formulé como nueva pregunta, te paso el link por las dudas
